# Fields not getting sorted in alphabetical order in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I have a few documents with the a name field in it. I am using analyzed version of the name field for search and `not_analyzed` for sorting purposes. The sorting happens in one level, that is the names are sorted alphabetically at first. But within the list of an alphabet, the names are getting sorted lexicographically rather than alphabetically. 
Here is the mapping I have used:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "seing": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Can anyone provide a solution for the same?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, what results you see and what you expect instead?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Digging down into Elasticsearch documents, I stumbled upon this:

- [Sorting and Collations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/sorting-collations.html#case-insensitive-sorting)

**Case-Insensitive Sorting**

> Imagine that we have three user documents whose name fields contain
>   Boffey, BROWN, and bailey, respectively. First we will apply the
>   technique described in String Sorting and Multifields of using a
>   not_analyzed field for sorting:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {                    //1
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {                 //2
              "type":  "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. The `analyzed` `name` field is used for search.
2. The `not_analyzed` `name.raw` field is used for sorting.

> The preceding search request would return the documents in this order:
>   BROWN, Boffey, bailey. This is known as lexicographical order as
>   opposed to alphabetical order. Essentially, the bytes used to
>   represent capital letters have a lower value than the bytes used to
>   represent lowercase letters, and so the names are sorted with the
>   lowest bytes first.
>
> That may make sense to a computer, but doesn’t make much sense to
>   human beings who would reasonably expect these names to be sorted
>   alphabetically, regardless of case. To achieve this, we need to index
>   each name in a way that the byte ordering corresponds to the sort
>   order that we want.
>
> In other words, we need an analyzer that will emit a single lowercase
>   token:

Following this logic, instead of storing raw document, you need to lowercase it using custom keyword analyzer:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings" : {
    "analysis" : {
      "analyzer" : {
        "case_insensitive_sort" : {
          "tokenizer" : "keyword",
          "filter" : ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "seing" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "fields" : {
            "raw" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "analyzer" : "case_insensitive_sort"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now ordering by `name.raw` should sort in *alphabetical* order, rather than *lexicographical*.

Quick test done on my local machine using Marvel:

Index structure:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "case_insensitive_sort": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "keyword": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Test data:

```
PUT /my_index/user/1
{
  "name": "Tim"
}

PUT /my_index/user/2
{
  "name": "TOM"
}
```

Query using raw field:

```
POST /my_index/user/_search
{
  "sort": "name.raw"
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "user",
  "_id" : "2",
  "_score" : null,
  "_source" : {
    "name" : "TOM"
  },
  "sort" : [
    "TOM"
  ]
},
{
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "user",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_score" : null,
  "_source" : {
    "name" : "Tim"
  },
  "sort" : [
    "Tim"
  ]
}
```

Query using lowercased string:

```
POST /my_index/user/_search
{
  "sort": "name.keyword"
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "user",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_score" : null,
  "_source" : {
    "name" : "Tim"
  },
  "sort" : [
    "tim"
  ]
},
{
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "user",
  "_id" : "2",
  "_score" : null,
  "_source" : {
    "name" : "TOM"
  },
  "sort" : [
    "tom"
  ]
}
```

I'm suspecting that second result is correct in your case.

Comment: The problem seems to be solved now. As you have shown, I should have used the "lowercase" filter.

Comment: If this helped for you. Perhaps it's worth checking it as an accepted answer?

Comment: Did your solution work to sort alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @Hamham I no longer remember that. You might have to make some adjustments to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

### Since Elastic 5.2, you can use a [normaliser](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html) to set up a case-insensitive sort.

The `normalizer` property of `keyword` fields is similar to
`analyzer` except that it guarantees that the analysis chain
produces a single token.

The `normalizer` is applied prior to indexing the keyword, as well as at
search-time when the `keyword` field is searched via a query parser such as
the `match` query.

```js
PUT index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [],
          "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT index/type/1
{
  "foo": "BÀR"
}

PUT index/type/2
{
  "foo": "bar"
}

PUT index/type/3
{
  "foo": "baz"
}

POST index/_refresh

GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "foo": "BAR"
    }
  }
}
```

The above query matches documents 1 and 2 since `BÀR` is converted to `bar` at
both index and query time.

```js
{
  "took": $body.took,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "type",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "foo": "bar"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "type",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "foo": "BÀR"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Also, the fact that keywords are converted prior to indexing also means that
aggregations return normalized values:

```js
GET index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "foo_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "foo"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

returns

```js
{
  "took": 43,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "foo_terms": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "bar",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "baz",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Source: [Normaliser](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html)

Comment: This is the way to go and was my problem. Where most answers, blogs etc just talk about using a keyword field when wanting to sort by for example a title field, it is not mentioned that sorting then is by lexicographical order. Or at least it is not made obvious

Comment: I think this is the way we should go if your elastic search version is beyond 5.x.x.

Answer (score 1):

Just some add-ons based on @PiwEL's answer.

If you are using [nodejs version](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) of elastic search, you **CAN NOT** really update the setting if your index already exists like this:

```
await esClient.indices.putSettings({
      index,
      body: {
        analysis: {
          normalizer: {
            my_normalizer: {
              type: "custom",
              char_filter: [],
              filter: ["lowercase", "asciifolding"],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

This API always throws exception. So I ended up creating this setting while creating the index, therefore the index has to be deleted and recreated. More details can be traced [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/140)

So the following works for me when using NodeJs client.

```
await esClient.indices.create({
  index,
  body: {
    settings: {
      analysis: {
        normalizer: {
          my_normalizer: {
            type: "custom",
            char_filter: [],
            filter: ["lowercase", "asciifolding"],
          },
        },
      },
    },
    mappings: {
      properties: {
        id: {
          type: "keyword",
        },
        name: {
          type: "text",
          fields: {
            keyword: {
              type: "keyword",
              normalizer: "my_normalizer",
            },
          },
        },
        seedless: {
          type: "boolean",
        },
        origin: { type: "text" },
      },
    },
  },
});
```