# Spring Elastic Search case insensitive sorting with Order.ignoreCase() not working

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to sort list of Person by their first name. using Open Declaration `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Order.Order.ignoreCase()` as shown below.

```
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Order;

    Order sortOrfer = new Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "firstName").ignoreCase();
```

In ES repository, I have person name with different cases. for example.

- Sachin
- ajai
- Dhoni

I am expecting the sorted data as shown below.

- ajai
- Dhoni
- Sachin

But the data is sorted as below, which is not correct(not expected),

- Dhoni
- Sachin
- ajai

the root cause of this behavior is that for `ajai` first letter is in small case. According to ES cases insensitive sorting is supported, Can any one tell me how can I fix this?

Comment: What is the mapping for firstName?  Have you read through this section on sorting?  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-fields.html  We recently re-indexed one field to be case-insensitive for sorting by applying a lowercase analyzer to the raw field.

Comment: what do you mean by mapping? `spring-es` provides `Order.ignoreCase()` which should work without applying a lowercase analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

The package you are calling is part of core spring data, not ES specific.  Elasticsearch must be setup with the proper mapping, and indexed with those settings. As far as I know, Elasticsearch has no such ability in Query DSL to sort the way you're asking (alphabetical vs lexicographical).  If you are trying to sort on the client-side, that would only sort the results returned for the first page, probably not what you are intending.

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33387493/880884) which worked for us.

Comment: I am using spring-data, so `.ignoreCase()` should work.