# ElasticSearch is not sorting file names in correct order

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-6

This is a contrived example to illustrate my problem.  I have a bunch of filename that I would like to sort alphabetically in the same way macOS might do in a finder window.

These are my indexed file names in the order I would expect to see them sorted:

```
A Tribe Called Quest - Can I Kick It (1).mp3
a.png
Bcc 05.png
Birling Gap Cliffs.jpg
Durdle Door.jpg
f.png
Frost.jpg
p.png
Users order.mp4
z.png
```

And this is what I'm doing in Kibana dev tools to test:

```
## sorting contrived example
# create the index with keyword filename for sorting
PUT /file-names
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc" : {
      "properties": {
        "filename": { "type": "keyword" }
      }
    }
  }
}

# create bunch of documents
POST file-names/_doc/_bulk
{ "index":{} }
{ "filename":"A Tribe Called Quest - Can I Kick It (1).mp3" }
{ "index":{} }
{ "filename":"a.png" }
{ "index":{} }
{ "filename":"Bcc 05.png" }
{ "index":{} }
{ "filename":"Birling Gap Cliffs.jpg" }
{ "index":{} }
{ "filename":"Durdle Door.jpg" }
{ "index":{} }
{ "filename":"Frost.jpg" }
{ "index":{} }
{ "filename":"f.png" }
{ "index":{} }
{ "filename":"Users order.mp4" }
{ "index":{} }
{ "filename":"p.png" }
{ "index":{} }
{ "filename":"z.png" }

# query with sort - bugged
GET /file-names/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "filename": {
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

The results I'm getting back are:

```
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "file-names",..."_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "filename" : "A Tribe Called Quest - Can I Kick It (1).mp3"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "A Tribe Called Quest - Can I Kick It (1).mp3"
        ]
      },
      {
        ...
        "_source" : {
          "filename" : "Bcc 05.png"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "Bcc 05.png"
        ]
      },
      {
        ...
        "_source" : {
          "filename" : "Birling Gap Cliffs.jpg"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "Birling Gap Cliffs.jpg"
        ]
      },
      {
        ...
        "_source" : {
          "filename" : "Durdle Door.jpg"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "Durdle Door.jpg"
        ]
      },
      {
        ...
        "_source" : {
          "filename" : "Frost.jpg"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "Frost.jpg"
        ]
      },
      {
        ...
        "_source" : {
          "filename" : "Users order.mp4"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "Users order.mp4"
        ]
      },
      {
        ...
        "_source" : {
          "filename" : "a.png"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "a.png"
        ]
      },
      {
        ...
        "_source" : {
          "filename" : "f.png"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "f.png"
        ]
      },
      {
        ...
        "_source" : {
          "filename" : "p.png"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "p.png"
        ]
      },
      {
        ...
        "_source" : {
          "filename" : "z.png"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "z.png"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Which are not in the order I'd expect.  You can see "a.png" is below "Users order.mp4" for reasons I cannot understand.

Any help appreciated to get sorting working in the order I'd expect!

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382734/fields-not-getting-sorted-in-alphabetical-order-in-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

As @Alper suggested, this has already been [addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382734/fields-not-getting-sorted-in-alphabetical-order-in-elasticsearch).

If you for some reason need to stick with the `keyword` mapping, here's how you can [script-sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting):

```
GET /file-names/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "string",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "doc['filename'].value.toLowerCase()"
      },
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```