# Improve sorting of elasticsearch queries

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I would like to improve both queries with ElasticSearch (6.8.x). ES is storing data build like this : `([a-z]{1-3}\w)` and are code for astronomical objects. Exemple : M1, M13, M42, M101 (from m1 to m110) or NGC10, NGC1085 etc from (ngc1 to ngc7840).

My ES mapping :

```json
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        // id, e.g: m1, m31, ngc1023...
        "id": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "copy_to": "suggest"
        },
        // Integer value for sorting : can be remove if useless
        "order": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        // list of name, e.g. : "Crab nebula, Messier 1..."
        "desigs": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer",
          "copy_to": "suggest"
        },
        // Other fields not used fot sorting
        "suggest": {
          "type" : "completion"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For first query, i would like items are sorted like this : m1, m2, m3,....m10,m11..., m99,m100, m101...
With this sort :

```json
{
  "query": {...},
  "sort": {
    "id": {"order": "asc"}
  }
}
```

I have this error : `Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [id] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index`

With this sort:

```json
{
  "query": {...},
  "sort": {
    "order.keyword": {"order": "asc"}
  }
}
```

but it's sorted like this : `m1, m10, m100, m101...,m11...m19, m2, m20`

For second query, i don't have adding sorting yet, it's for an autocomplete search. The query :

```json
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query": "m10", 
      "fields": [ "id", "id.raw", "desigs"],
      "type": "phrase_prefix" 
    }
  }
```

If i'm looking for "m10", i will have : m103, m100, m106...m10. I would like in results : m10, m101, m102. Is it possible with same sort  as above ? Or an other ?

Comment: Could the data be stored in two fields: one for the catalogue name (Eg. "M" or "NGC") and the other as a numeric index?

Comment: The second field exist: it's "order". Maybe the type is not good and i need to change "text" to "integer"

Comment: Yes, if you want to sort in numeric order then having an integer value to sort makes it much easier.

Comment: Maybe my solution is here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33387493/3279873